# iOS custom keyboard accents

Tags: ios, keyboard, inputview

I want to make a custom keyboard. Some characters have multiple options (like in the picture). What is the best approach to emulate this behaviour?
I tried adding a subview on top of the custom keyboard view, but that is not responding to any events. Probably because the underlying UIButton is still taking care of the touch events.

[image: http://www.retrevo.com/content/files/images/misc/iphoneshortcut_accentletter.jpg]

Comment: Did you found an answer? I have the same problem

Comment: Sorry, no. But it has been a while since I tried that. Maybe things have changed now in the API's.